# Flex: Points to pixels and back again

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, graphics

So I have extended the PlotChart that comes with Flex to have the ability to draw trend-lines. To do this, I have to get pixel positions. How can I convert (100px,100px) in pixels to a point on the graph, such as (0.7,1.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlotSeries::dataToLocal(...) ended up working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw on charts using the CartesianChartCanvas, here is the link to the LiveDoc: [Drawing on Chart Controls](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html)

To answer your question more specifically, CartesianChartCanvas supports drawing by pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a subclass of ChartElement, and add it to annotationElements for your chart. The docs for Flex 2 show an example: [Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=charts_formatting_110_10.html)